# Package and Activity name

Tags: android, android-activity, package

Good day. I'm working on an android program which is application manager. I want to call the application of "Dictionary.com" but in my code, I should include the package and activity name of this application. Can someone post here the Package name and Activity name of this Application? Please. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Also, the "Translate free" application. PLEASE. I really need this. This kind of application manager is my PROject. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Application name is something that visible to the user. So put some user friendly name such as "Digital PocketDictionary"

Package name should be unique. It is recommended if you can use your domain in reverse version. As an example, if you have your own hosting or a website related to this app such as *www.digitaldic.com* you can use **com.digital.dictionary** as the package name. Make sure all the letters are simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to get what you are asking for, specially the activity name. But here's what you could do to get the package name.

Install the required apps on your phone and then connect it to your computer and in your Eclipse, go to the "DDMS" perspective. In the devices window, click on your phone's entry. On the right, go to the File Explorer.

Go to system/app. You should see the name of the .apk file. You'll get the name of the package in the "info" column.

Getting the name of the activity might be difficult. you could contact Dictionary.com to get the info, coz I doubt you will be able to start the activity, if Dictionary.com doesn't allow it.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this code and it works without having to include the activity's name:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.test3");
if (!i.equals(null)){
    startActivity(i);
}else{
    System.out.println("too bad (-*-)");
}
```